# Finding Eigen Vectors and Respective Eigen Values for 3x3 Matrice

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

We are given the following matrix:

```
| 5   2   0 |
| 2   5   0 |
|-3   4   6 |
```

Then told to find the respective eigen values and their vectors.

I did this a few days ago as part of a test and received the values 3,6 and 14/9. Which these answers were selected as the correct answers. However upon re-visiting this question as I found it odd. I realized I had made a mistake in my calculations. However after doing this multiple times and coming to the same answer (listed below), this does not work out the way it should. Would someone please correct me as to where I am going wrong,this seemed to work perfectly fine a few days ago but for some reason I seem to be going wrong somewhere.

My calculations:

```
|  5-λ  2    0   |
|  2    5-λ  0   |
|  -3   4    6-λ |
```

---

```
(5-λ) | 5-λ  0   |  - 2 |  2   0  | + 0 
      |  4   6-λ |      | -3  6-λ |
```

---

```
(5-λ)((5-λ)(6-λ)-0) - 2((2)(6-λ)-0)
```

---

```
-λ^3 + 16λ^2-81λ+126
```

---

```
-λ^2(λ-16)-9(9λ-14)
```

---

```
(-λ^2 - 9)(λ-16)(9λ-14)
```

Please correct me if I am wrong. Is there something I am missing here. Do not worry about the eigenvectors for now. My brain does not appear to be working as well today.

Comment: The last equation can't be right since it is fourth order in $\lambda$ and should be cubic.

Comment: @Moo where am I going wrong baring expanding the last column? Oh and regarding

Comment: @EthanBolker You will have to forgive me. I only recently learnt how to group 4 term polynomials so it is highly likely there is something wrong there.. Please do correct me

Comment: For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [here](/help/notation), [here](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [here](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [here](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Comment: @AnotherUser Beautiful, thanks. Was struggling to find that page.

Comment: Going from the second to last line to the last line... it is as though you thought $ab + cd = (a+c)(b+d)$ but that is wrong.  Recall that $(a+c)(b+d) = ab \color{red}{+ad+cb}+cd$.  The common teaching mnemonic is FOIL - Firsts, Outers, Inners, Lasts.  You forgot about the Outers and Inners in FOIL.

Comment: @Moo thanks. I of it was my factoring. I have only recently started reteaching myself maths. I used to really good when I was younger (Mensa and what not) but sort of fell off around 14. Realised now I could not group that way. Just learnt about finding rational 0's and got the right answer. Incredibly sorry for wasting your time with my stupidity. Thank you though!

Comment: @JMoravitz I am really out of touch with a lot of my basics from what I am seeing. I have corrected it now. Thanks

Comment: @Moo last question. Just learnt about synthetic division, is this a good way to go about it or is there a faster way? Assuming I cannot group straight away obviously. The only reason I ended up coming back to this (Which I am glad I did). Was because I was attempting to diagonalize a matrix without knowing the eigen values and vectors and it was going incredibly wrong.

Comment: It is easier to keep $(6 - \lambda)$ factored out when simplifying the polynomial

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Generally for a $3 \times 3$ matrix, the trick is to not expand but factorize the terms first. In the columns of the matrix, try to exploit the only term in the columns with the rest of the terms being $0$. At times, you may have to use Gaussian elimination to simplify your matrix.

For this case, exploit the third column of the matrix.

The solution is as follows.
$$\text{det} \begin{bmatrix} 
5-λ & 2 & 0 \\
2 & 5-λ & 0 \\  
-3 & 4 & 6-λ \\
\end{bmatrix} = 
(6-\lambda) \space 
\text{det} \begin{bmatrix} 
5-λ & 2 \\
2 & 5-λ \\  
\end{bmatrix} =
(6-\lambda)((5-\lambda)^2-4) = 
(6-\lambda)((5-\lambda)^2-2^2) = 
(6-\lambda)(5-\lambda-2)(5-\lambda+2) =
(6-\lambda)(3-\lambda)(7-\lambda) = 0
$$
Hence, the eigenvalues are given by
$$
\lambda_1 = 3, \lambda_2 = 6, \lambda_3 = 7.
$$

To find the eigenvector, plug in the respective eigenvalues.

For $\lambda_1 = 3$,
$$\boldsymbol{A}-3\boldsymbol{I} = \begin{bmatrix} 
2 & 2 & 0 \\
2 & 2 & 0 \\  
-3 & 4 & 3 \\
\end{bmatrix}$$.

Pick any two linearly independent vectors from the matrix and take the cross-product. You can only do this $\mathbb{R}^3$. For this case, I choose columns $2$ and $3$ as it is easy to compute.
$$\boldsymbol{v}_1 = \begin{bmatrix} 
1\\
1\\  
2\\
\end{bmatrix} \times \begin{bmatrix} 
0\\
0\\  
1\\
\end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix} 
1\\
-1\\  
0\\
\end{bmatrix}$$

I am sure you can compute the other values as well. Hope it helps.

Comment: That is a pretty nifty shortcut actually. I am a little uncertain as to what order the Eigen values should be. However I notice you put them in ascending order. Is this the standard format? I have only recently started with Linear Algebra so I still have a long way to go. I will go check out cross product, have not used that method before.

Comment: It is pretty straightforward. If your matrix is $3 \times 3$, you will get a cubic characteristic polynomial. Likewise for a $4 \times 4$ matrix, characteristic polynomial will be of fourth-order. You can express in any format as long as the eigenvalues corresponds to the correct eigenvectors. Cross-product method only works in $\mathbb{R}^3$ and if there are no repeated eigenvalues. I suggest reading up materials on Linear Algebra. There may be some proofs, lemmas or methods to aid in solving certain problems.

Comment: Thanks, will do so.