# Calculating eigenvalues of a matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, characteristic-polynomial

I have this quadratic matrix:
\begin{align*}
A = \begin{bmatrix}
0 & -1 & -2\\
-1 & 0 & -2\\
-2 & -2 & -3
\end{bmatrix} \implies A - \lambda I = \begin{bmatrix}
0 - \lambda & -1 & -2\\
-1 & 0 - \lambda & -2\\
-2 & -2 & -3 - \lambda
\end{bmatrix}
\end{align*}
After forming the characteristic polynomial and using the Rule of Sarrus, I get this equation:
$$-\lambda^3 - 3\lambda^2 + 9\lambda - 5$$
However the correct form of this term would be:
$$-(5 + \lambda)(1 - \lambda)^2$$
So the eigenvalues are $1$ and $-5$.
The thing I do not understand, is how to form this equation to get the values. Which approach and rules can solve this?

Thank you very much.

Comment: Can you see that $\lambda = 1$ is a root of $p(\lambda) = -\lambda^{3} - 3 \lambda^{2} + 9 \lambda - 5$ by inspection? If so, let $p(\lambda) = (\lambda - 1)(\lambda + a_{1})(\lambda + a_{2})$, then expand the right hand side and then equate to find the $a_{i}$. Or use long division.

Comment: To be clear, although your question originated from an exercise involving eigenvalues... your question actually can be phrased to have nothing to do with eigenvalues and linear algebra in general.  You are simply asking how to factor a cubic polynomial (*one which came from a textbook exercise and so is expected to have convenient answers*).  This should have been prerequisite knowledge taught well before this.

Comment: The punchline should be for most students that (1) You should know how to factor a quadratic, (2) You should know how to perform polynomial long division, and (3) You should hope that the exercise was nice enough to give at least one "nice" root that can be found by trial and error or inspection (*usually 0, +1, -1, +2, -2, +10, -10 or similar that requires minimal calculation*).  With these you can spot the first root, perform division, and complete the problem with the quadratic formula.

Comment: There do exist more generic methods for those less conveniently crafted problems whose answers are not as pretty to factor cubics and even quartics, however apart from a few special cases students are generally not expected to memorize these (*though they are expected to learn of their existence*).  See [mrmath's blog post](https://www.mrmath.com/misfit/algebra-stuff/the-cubic-and-quartic-formulas/).  For quintic and higher, [it is proven](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abel%E2%80%93Ruffini_theorem) that there can not exist such a formula involving radicals to solve the general form.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> $$p(\lambda)=-\lambda^3 - 3\lambda^2 + 9\lambda - 5$$

Proceed from your work,

$$\begin{align}
p(\lambda)&=-\lambda^3-5\lambda^2+2\lambda^2+9\lambda-5\\
\\
&=-\lambda^2(\lambda+5)+(2\lambda-1)(\lambda+5)\\
\\
&=(\lambda+5)(-\lambda^2+2\lambda-1)\\
\\
&=-(\lambda+5)(\lambda^2-2\lambda+1)\\
\\
&=-(\lambda+5)(\lambda-1)^2\end{align}
$$

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [rational roots theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rational_root_theorem).

In your case, the equation reads

$$-x^3 - 3x^2 + 9x - 5$$

so you may expect that every rational root must be among the numbers $\{\pm 1, \pm 5\}$ as indeed is.

Answer (score 0):

For matrices of $\mathbb{R}^{3 \times 3}$ and above, the method is to try to apply row operations and factorize. Avoid computing the determinant directly, or expanding the terms first.

1. Apply row operations to $ |A - \lambda I|$.
   $$
   \begin{matrix}
   \\
   -R_1+R_2 \rightarrow\\
   \\
   \end{matrix}
   \begin{vmatrix}
   -\lambda & -1 & -2 \\
   -1 & -\lambda & -2 \\
   -2 & -2 & -3 -\lambda \\
   \end{vmatrix}
   \implies
   \begin{vmatrix}
   -\lambda & -1 & -2 \\
   -(1-\lambda) & 1-\lambda & 0 \\
   -2 & -2 & -3-\lambda \\
   \end{vmatrix}
   $$
2. Find the characteristic polynomial from the reduced expression. We will exploit column $3$.
   $$
   \begin{align} 
   p(\lambda) = & -2 \bigl( 2(1-\lambda) + 2(1-\lambda) \bigl) + (-3-\lambda)\bigl( -\lambda(1-\lambda) -(1-\lambda)  \bigl)\\
   = & -8(1-\lambda) + (-3-\lambda)(1-\lambda)(-\lambda-1)\\
   = & -8(1-\lambda) + (3+\lambda)(1-\lambda)(1+\lambda)\\
   = & (1-\lambda)\bigl(-8 + (3+\lambda)(1+\lambda) \bigl) \\
   = & (1-\lambda)(-8+\lambda^2+4\lambda+3)\\
   = & (1-\lambda)(\lambda^2+4\lambda-5)\\
   = & (1-\lambda)(\lambda+5)(\lambda-1)\\
   = & -(1-\lambda)^2(\lambda+5)
   \end{align}
   $$

You may refer to a similar question I have answered.

Link: [Finding Eigen Vectors and Respective Eigen Values for 3x3 Matrice](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4478876/finding-eigen-vectors-and-respective-eigen-values-for-3x3-matrice/4479064?noredirect=1#comment9396201_4479064)