# Eigenvalues of a certain $3\times3$ matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

I have an exam coming up next week and I've been doing some previous years exams to train.
There is this exercise where I have to find the eigenvalues of the following matrix :

$$
\left (
\begin{matrix}
7 & 1 & 1 \\
1 & 7 & 1 \\
1 & 1 & 7 \\
\end{matrix} \right )
$$

I tried many ways and each time I find a polynomial that is nearly impossible to solve without a calculator (and of course calculators are not allowed during the exam) :

$$-\lambda^3+21\lambda^2-144\lambda+324$$

I feel like maybe there could be a way to simplify the matrix but I don't know how. I would be grateful for any help, even just some hint.

Thank you

Comment: Not that this really helps you too much, but if the sum of the entries of each row or column of an $n\times n$ matrix adds up to some number $m$, then $m$ is an eigenvalue of that matrix. In this case, the sum of all the entries in each column adds up to $9$. Thus, $9$ is an eigenvalue of that matrix.

Comment: I have answered a fairly similar question before. You may refer to the post here: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4513346/calculating-eigenvalues-of-a-matrix/4516152#4516152 

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 1):

The matrix $M$ with all its entries equal to one is proportional to a rank one projector. More precisely, define the following $N$-dimensional normalized (column) vector:

$$
v = \frac{1}{\sqrt{N}} (1,1,\ldots,1)^T
$$

Then,

$$
M = N v v^T\,.
$$

Since the matrix $v v^T$ is an orthogonal projector, it's eigenvalues are $0$ and $1$.

With these information you should easily get the eigenvalues of your matrix.

Comment: you may have overlooked that  the diagonal entries are not the same as other entries.

Comment: Thanks but I think you may have overlooked the fact that a shift by a multiple of the identity matrix results in a simple shift of the eigenvalues

Answer (score 1):

Let $A=$
$
\left (
\begin{matrix}
7 & 1 & 1 \\
1 & 7 & 1 \\
1 & 1 & 7 \\
\end{matrix} \right )
$, consider $|A-\lambda I_3|$:

$
\left |
\begin{matrix}
7-\lambda & 1 & 1 \\
1 & 7-\lambda & 1 \\
1 & 1 & 7-\lambda \\
\end{matrix} \right|=
\left |
\begin{matrix}
7-\lambda & 1 & 1 \\
0 & 6-\lambda & \lambda -6\\
1 & 1 & 7-\lambda \\
\end{matrix} \right|=
\left |
\begin{matrix}
7-\lambda & 2 & 1 \\
0 & 0 & \lambda -6\\
1 & 8-\lambda & 7-\lambda \\
\end{matrix} \right|=\\
(6-\lambda)\left |
\begin{matrix}
7-\lambda & 2 \\
1 & 8-\lambda \\
\end{matrix} \right|=(6-\lambda)(\lambda^2-15\lambda+54)=(6-\lambda)(\lambda-6)(\lambda-9)
$

It follows:

$\lambda_1=6 \quad \mu(\lambda_1)=2\\
\lambda_2=9 \quad \mu(\lambda_2)=1$

Answer (score 0):

I think the most straightforward is to set $a=7-\lambda$ and sum to first column then subtract rows.

$\begin{vmatrix} a&1&1\\ 1&a&1\\ 1&1&a\\
\end{vmatrix}=\begin{vmatrix} a+2&1&1\\ a+2&a&1\\ a+2&1&a\\
\end{vmatrix}=\begin{vmatrix} a+2&1&1\\ 0&a-1&0\\ 0&0&a-1\\
\end{vmatrix}=(a-1)^2(a+2)$

Answer (score 0):

It is easy to see that (1 1 1) is an eigenvector with eigenvalue $9$. This means that $9$ must be a root of your polynomial and you can factorize by $\lambda-9$. Just do the sum of the columns to check.

By the way, when you face a polynomial of degree $3$ like that, you can just try to find the rational roots using the rule https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rational_root_theorem . Very often, in the exercises, the eigenvalues are simple so using this rule you will be able to find them.

Otherwise, as  a general rule, you should not expand brutally your determinant in a degree $3$ polynomial. You need to first find an eigenvalue/eigenvector to factorize the determinant during the process. This will be much easier as it will directly lead to a partially factorized form of the polynomial.